# How do i restore files from the recycle bin of an external hard disk drive

Tags: windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, file-recovery, recycle-bin

Before i removed the hard drive of my PC to make it external, i moved a 
folder to the recycle bin. I have a $Recycler.bin folder that contains 5 folder and 2 files. Now that the hard drive is external, how do i
restore the folders and files in the recycle bin of my external hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

The actual location of the Recycle Bin depends on the type of operating system and file system. On older FAT file systems, it is located in `Drive:\RECYCLED`. In the NTFS filesystem it is `Drive:\RECYCLER`. On Windows 7 and newer it is `Drive:\$Recycle.Bin` folder.

So in your case, since you have a Windows 8.1 machine, it would be `C:\$Recycle.Bin` folder (but you may need to change the `C` part in that).

Comment: so how do i change the location?

Comment: why would you want to change the location ??

Answer (score 1):

If you can see `$Recycler.bin` on the external drive (which you might well, according to [this associated question](https://superuser.com/questions/331435/why-does-an-external-usb-hdd-have-a-working-recycle-bin?rq=1)), then, obviously, you can restore or copy from there.

If not, you may have to put the drive back into your PC in order to restore the folder.

No, wait, I take that back. If the drive was your C:\ drive before, then it ought to be bootable. Adjust your BIOS to boot from it, or try F11 or F12 at boot time, boot form the external drive & restore the files.

---

[Update] Try a file undeleter, like [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva)

Comment: The windows on the external hard drive is corrupt and i couldn't recover it. So its not bootable

Comment: I see. Well, if you can see the `$Recycler.bin` folder, then copy form there. If you cannot, the try a file undeleter, like https://www.piriform.com/recuva (ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for more). Just curious  - what backup scheme have you put in place now, to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably get another external hard drive for the purpose of storing all my important files alone.

Comment: Hopefully always having two copies of them